# Inserting an image below sliders in wxPython

Tags: python, image, user-interface, wxpython

I want to have an image below a slider in a wxpython GUI. The text asks "What is the value?" and I want to have a picture of a value (such as 35) below the slider, and have different images that change as you navigate through.

I have researched this issue, but only found ways to make an image the entire background, rather then appear in the panel.

```
import wx

class MyPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent, id):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, id)
        self.SetBackgroundColour("white")
        text1 = wx.StaticText(self, -1, "What is the value", (10,10))
        self.slider1 = wx.Slider(self, -1, 50, 0, 100, (10, 40), (200, 50),
            wx.SL_HORIZONTAL | wx.SL_AUTOTICKS | wx.SL_LABELS)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_SLIDER, self.sliderUpdate)

    def sliderUpdate(self, event):
        self.pos1 = self.slider1.GetValue()
        if self.pos1 == 35:
            box = wx.MessageDialog(None, "BINGO!", "Title", wx.OK)
            box.ShowModal()

app = wx.App()
frame = wx.Frame(None, -1, "Title", size = (400, 310))
MyPanel(frame,-1)
frame.Show(True)
app.MainLoop()
```

Additionally, I am unsure how to create multiple pages to switch the pictures at the bottom and have a submit button that checks if it is correct before moving on.

Any literature or videos that you can point me to to better learn wxpython would be appreciated as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the image to the panel in the required position or start using `sizers`.
I've added some quick `PIL` code to generate an image of a number or text, so that you can generate your image on the fly if you need to, although I have left it as a single global instance. You may want to make it a function.

```
import wx
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
temp_img=[]
for i in range(101):
    img = Image.new('RGB', (100,30))
    d = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
    d.text((10,10), str(i))
    width, height = img.size
    temp_img.append(wx.Bitmap.FromBuffer(width, height, img.tobytes()))

class MyPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent, id):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, id)
        self.SetBackgroundColour("white")
        text1 = wx.StaticText(self, -1, "What is the value", (10,10))
        self.slider1 = wx.Slider(self, -1, 50, 0, 100, (10, 40), (200, 50),
            wx.SL_HORIZONTAL | wx.SL_AUTOTICKS | wx.SL_LABELS)
        self.bmp = wx.StaticBitmap(self, -1, bitmap=temp_img[50], pos=(10,100))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_SLIDER, self.sliderUpdate)

    def sliderUpdate(self, event):
        self.pos1 = self.slider1.GetValue()
        self.bmp.SetBitmap(temp_img[self.pos1])
        if self.pos1 == 35:
            box = wx.MessageDialog(None, "BINGO 35!", "Title", wx.OK)
            box.ShowModal()

app = wx.App()
frame = wx.Frame(None, -1, "Title", size = (400, 310))
MyPanel(frame,-1)
frame.Show(True)
app.MainLoop()
```

[image]

Edited to show multiple images based on the slider value.

Comment: I did not know there was a static image function that would do that. Thank you! How would this work if I wanted to include a picture of a horse or something not created by PIL? Would you just use the file path to the image as temp_image?

Comment: A comment has to have >15 characters as a preamble to the answer `Yes` Although an image of 35 horses might seem a little strange. ;)

Comment: Edited code to change the image based on the slider value.